# SPHINX BOOTSTRAP THEME | Not working correctly

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, css, python-sphinx

I am migrating a Sphinx Documentation, from `read_the_docs` to `sphinx_bootstrap_theme`. I am having problems though, and a lot of them.

PROBLEM 1: **Bootstrap theme isn't loading javascript parts**
While most of the CSS of the theme, is working, the Javascript parts, that are depended on JQuery aren't getting loaded.

What I tried:

```
Insert the cdn for JQuery in my layout.html. Didn't work.
```

PROBLEM 2: **Navbar isn't working correctly**

I get the most part of the navigation bar as it should be. The links are there the title, the searchbox. But the CSS is completly screwed.

```
The title is on the right, the navigation menu is is a list view on the left.
```

PROBLEM 3: **Sidebar T.O.C isn't working**

I want my `globaltoc.html` to be present in the left sidebar. Currently is it not showing anything besides the `TABLE OF CONTENTS`title that I hardcoded in there.

What I did so  far:

```
Created a `globaltoc.html` and inserted the following:
{#
    basic/globaltoc.html
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    Sphinx sidebar template: global table of contents.

    :copyright: Copyright 2007-2019 by the Sphinx team, see AUTHORS.
    :license: BSD, see LICENSE for details.
#}
<h3><a href="{{ pathto(master_doc) }}">{{ _('Table of Contents') }}</a></h3>
{{ toctree() }}
```

I would really like some help, with the following. I am really confused about this framework. Even if you point me somewhere for help it would be great.

So to sum up the question and help you answer them.

1. How do I include JS, and the JQuery dependancy on a sphinx project?
2. How do I make sure all the bootstrap CSS classes work as intended?
3. How do I show the table of content in every page correctly?

Comment: Did you read the project's conveniently named [README](https://github.com/ryan-roemer/sphinx-bootstrap-theme#customization)? No one can reproduce the issue without seeing your `conf.py`. Suggest comparing it to the [demo's `conf.py`](https://github.com/ryan-roemer/sphinx-bootstrap-theme/blob/master/demo/source/conf.py).

Comment: Yeah man, I did. Even the conf.py, I copied. It does not work. I will update with my `conf.py`. Now let me try to find an answer.

Comment: I'd suggest creating a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As it is you don't provide any information to help identify the cause of the issues you report.